# OxyPlot fails to render in Xamarin Forms UWP

Tags: .net, uwp, xamarin.forms, oxyplot, xamarin.uwp

Following [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1167724/Using-OxyPlot-with-Xamarin-Forms) simple example I'm just playing about embedding OxyPlot in a Xamarin Forms Sample app. I've created a brand new Xamarin Forms App, added the Nuget packages and in each project added the required Init code for OxyPlot.
Then, in my MainPage.xaml I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:oxy="clr-namespace:OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms;assembly=OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OxyPlotTestApp"
             x:Class="OxyPlotTestApp.MainPage">

    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding PieModel}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="20,0,.9,.9" 
                      AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="WidthProportional,HeightProportional" />
    </AbsoluteLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

And in the codebehind:

```
using OxyPlot;
using OxyPlot.Axes;
using OxyPlot.Series;
using OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace OxyPlotTestApp
{
    public class PieViewModel
    {
        public PlotModel PieModel { get; set; }

        public PieViewModel()
        {
            PieModel = CreatePieChart();

        }

        private PlotModel CreatePieChart()
        {
            var model = new PlotModel { Title = "World Population By Content" };
            var ps = new PieSeries
            {
                StrokeThickness = .25,
                InsideLabelPosition = 0.25,
                AngleSpan = 360,
                StartAngle = 0
            };
            ps.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Africa", 1030) { IsExploded = false });
            ps.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Americas", 929) { IsExploded = false });
            ps.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Asia", 4157));
            ps.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Europe", 739) { IsExploded = false });
            ps.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Oceania", 35) { IsExploded = false });
            model.Series.Add(ps);
            return model;
        }

    }
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public PieViewModel vm { get; set; }
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            vm = new PieViewModel();
            this.BindingContext = vm;
        }

    }
}
```

I'm not sure what, if anything, I've missed out, but I've tried both the UWP project and the Android project (the latter on a  physical device) and its fine on Android but the UWP app just renders a blank page.

My UWP App.xaml.cs (relevant part):

```
if (rootFrame == null)
            {
                // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
                rootFrame = new Frame();

                rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

                OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.PlotViewRenderer.Init();

                Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e);
```

Thanks...

**Edit:**

I've just created a new test project and get the exact same results, so its not project or machine specific for me...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you mentioned, a PieChart working on Android but not on UWP with Xamarin.Forms (3.1.0.697729).
I finally made it work on UWP by installing the latest version of OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms/1.1.0-unstable0011) instead of the 1.0.0. It works fine for a PieChart, I did not test other plots.

In addition, the Oxyplot documentation [here](https://github.com/oxyplot/docs/blob/master/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms.rst) says that "the VerticalOptions and HorizontalOptions properties must be set" but you also need to set the HeightRequest and WidthRequest. I read that in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46938602/oxyplot-not-showing-in-xamarin-forms?rq=1), but contrary to this post, it works fine in a StackLayout for me.
The question is old but I hope it will help !