# OxyPlot not showing in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, oxyplot

There are dozens of issues about this particular problem, but none of the proposed solutions have worked for me. I cannot get OxyPlot to appear in iOS or Android. I've followed the setup instructions to add the various Init methods after Xamarin Forms init. What I have tried so far:

- Adding HeightRequest + WidthRequest
- Not putting it in a stack layout
- Adding a dummy variable after init
- Going to the latest unstable version via OxyPlot's nuget feed (https://www.myget.org/F/oxyplot)

I am using Xamarin Android version 25.4.0.2, Xamarin Forms 2.4.0.18342, and OxyPlot version 1.0.0.

Here's the XAML:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:oxy="clr-namespace:OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms;assembly=OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms"
        x:Class="Example.Stats"
        NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <AbsoluteLayout>  
            <oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding Model}"  
                  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="20,0,.9,.9" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="WidthProportional,HeightProportional" />  
        </AbsoluteLayout>  
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

And the partial class:

```
namespace Gatemaster
{
    public partial class Stats : ContentPage
    {
        public PlotModel Model { 
            get {
                var model = new PlotModel { Title = "World population by continent" };  
                var ps = new PieSeries  
                {        
                    StrokeThickness = .25,  
                    InsideLabelPosition = .25,  
                    AngleSpan = 360,  
                    StartAngle = 0  
                };  

                // http://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/world_population.htm  
                // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continent  
                ps.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Africa", 1030) { IsExploded = false });  
                ps.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Americas", 929) { IsExploded = false });  
                ps.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Asia", 4157));  
                ps.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Europe", 739) { IsExploded = false });  
                ps.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Oceania", 35) { IsExploded = false });  
                model.Series.Add(ps);
                return model;
            } 
            private set { 

            } 
        }

        public Stats()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't appear to be setting your BindingContext

Comment: @Jason Is that required in this instance? I've been able to bind to properties on the partial class before without setting it.

Comment: AFAIK, you can either set it explicitly or inherit it, but it has to be set somewhere

Comment: Have you tried setting vertical and horizontal options to centre and the height/width request at the same time? I've got mine inside a grid and this works for me: <oxy:PlotView x:Name="GraphPanel" Model="{Binding ChartData}"   Grid.Row="3"
                VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="500" HeightRequest="300" />

Comment: @Jason: Welp, you were right. `BindingContext = this;` in the initializer made the graph appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Jason, I missed setting BindingContext. I find it incredibly odd that an error wasn't being thrown about a missing property...